# Running preprocessor based on using make command or makefile

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, c-preprocessor

In GCC we can run simple preprocessor as:

```
g++ -E x.cpp > temp.cpp
```

However, in larger projects where there are so many `makefile`s in place; it's very cumbersome to mention all the dependencies. E.g.

```
g++ -I /home/x1 -I /home/x2 ... -DMACRO1 -DMACRO2 ... -E x.cpp > temp.cpp
```

Is there any way by which using the `makefile`, we can run the C preprocessor ?

Comment: `makefile` can run `g++` with `-E`, just like it runs it without it. Just copy your normal compilation rule, and add `-E`.

Comment: Agree with @ugoren, you need to explain why this is anything other than a tiny change to your existing compilation rule for .cpp files.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, I want to do this on several individual files and redirect its output into another files one by one. Moreover, do I need to edit each and every makefile ?

Comment: Then copy your existing rule, and make a special rule for that one particular file (but adding `-E` etc.).  I don't know what you mean by "each and every makefile" - you need to edit as many makefiles as is necessary!

Comment: The `imake` program that was part of the X11 build system used the C preprocessor to convert an `Imakefile` into a `makefile`.  However, that's an evolutionary dead-end; I'm not even sure whether X11 still uses it.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use `-save-temps`? If your project has lots of makefiles, perhaps there's a top level one which defines the name / path to the compiler? I'd just hijack that to look something like:

```
CC = some-target-gcc -save-temps
```

Then you'll end up with a pile of `.i` files every time you build.

Answer (score 1):

Using the suffix `.cpp` for the pre-processed file is a bad idea as it clashes with the `.cpp` suffix of your C++ files.  Try something else - here's a snippet you can start with that uses the suffix `.e`:

```
CXX      = g++
CPPFLAGS = -E
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -DMACRO1 -DMACRO2
INCLUDES = -I /home/x1 -I /home/x2

%.e : %.c
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $< -o $@
```

Be careful to put a TAB at the start of the 'recipe' (the line "$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) ...").  The stuff above defines a rule that tells `make` how to build a `.e` file from a `.cpp` file.  With a file `x.cpp` you can use

```
make x.e
```

Notice that the -E flag is defined in CPPFLAGS.  This tells the compiler (g++) to stop after the preprocessing stage. The `-o` tells the compiler where to put the generated file, while the $@ is `make` shorthand for the `target`, in this case the `.e` file.  There is no need to redirect anything; g++ writes the `.e` file for you.

If you want to generate a `.e` file for a list of cpp files, do something like:

```
SRCS = a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp d.cpp
CPPS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.e)   

.PHONY:cpps
cpps: $(CPPS)
```

Then build them:

```
make cpps
```

Comment: CC is normally for the C compiler; CXX for the C++ compiler?

Comment: Do you mean, I need to put `-E` option and redirect to ".e" file with the same name? I don't see `-E` option in your answer though. Should I run `make x.cpp` or `make x.e` on *individual files* one by one?